# Python JSON unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, json

I am creating a Python script to parse the JSON response from https://vulners.com/api/v3/search/stats/

I have the following code in my .py:

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get('https://vulners.com/api/v3/search/stats/')
vuln_set = json.loads(response.text)

vuln_type = vuln_set['data']['type_results']
vuln_bulletinfamily = vuln_set['data']['type_results'][vuln_type]['bulletinFamily']
vuln_name = vuln_set['data']['type_results'][vuln_type]['displayName']

print("Type: " + vuln_type)
print("Bulletin Family: " + vuln_bulletinfamily)
print("Name: " + vuln_name)
```

I need to get the vuln_type aswell as the child information (vuln_bulletinfamily & vuln_name) 
An excerpt from the JSON response:

```
"data": {
"type_results": {
  "aix": {
    "lastUpdated": [],
    "bulletinFamily": "unix",
    "displayName": "IBM AIX",
    "lastrun": "2017-09-14T14:04:56",
    "count": 110,
    "workTime": "0:00:10.983795"
  },
  "akamaiblog": {
    "lastUpdated": [],
    "bulletinFamily": "blog",
    "displayName": "Akamai Blog",
    "lastrun": "2017-09-14T10:38:52",
    "count": 1463,
    "workTime": "0:00:00.358691"
  },
  "amazon": {
    "lastUpdated": [],
    "bulletinFamily": "unix",
    "displayName": "Amazon Linux AMI",
    "lastrun": "2017-09-14T14:17:40",
    "count": 889,
    "workTime": "0:00:01.839594"
  },
```

I am getting an error of TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
vuln_bulletinfamily = vuln_set['data']['type_results'][vuln_type]['bulletinFamily']
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: the keys have to be hashable. As a general rule, only immutable objects (strings, integers, floats, frozensets, tuples of immutables) are hashable (though exceptions are possible).

Comment: I've added the traceback to the above

Comment: You are passing a dict to be looked up as a dict key. `vuln_type = vuln_set['data']['type_results']`, its a dict try printing it. You need to select one of the possible keys from that dict to continue deeper into the hierarchy to `bulletinFamily`. It's not quite clear what you want to do, perhaps you intended to iterate over the items in the `type_results` dict?

Comment: This JSON file has a lot of the vuln_type dicts so wil I have to repeat the code for each one?

Comment: `vuln_bulletinfamily = vuln_set['data']['type_results'][vuln_type]['bulletinFamily']` - in this line, `vuln_type` is a type `dict`, dict keys can't be dicts. You need to loop through each key in vuln_type to access them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the traceback line, the next line and the first print line, you are trying to access a dict `type_results` and `vuln_type` with a key that is also a dictionary.
You need to loop through the keys, like:-

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get('https://vulners.com/api/v3/search/stats/')
vuln_set = json.loads(response.text)

vuln_type = vuln_set['data']['type_results']
for k in vuln_type :
    vuln_bulletinfamily = vuln_set['data']['type_results'][k]['bulletinFamily']
    vuln_name = vuln_set['data']['type_results'][k]['displayName']

    print("Type: " + k)
    print("Bulletin Family: " + vuln_bulletinfamily)
    print("Name: " + vuln_name)
```

Comment: That worked! I only started with python a couple of days ago, coming from PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
vuln_set = json.loads(response.text) vs response.json()
```